# Java Spring Hibernate Communications link failure

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My application is running in MySql 5.6, and I am using Hibernate, Spring and Tomcat7. Before my application was working perfectly in my personal computer (Windows 7 32bits) but i moved it to a server (Windows Server 2008 64 bits).

When I start the server, everything works until that it tries to load this library `"org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider".`

Actually the concret line is:

```
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing connection provider: 

org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider
```

And after this server is waiting around 45seconds trying to load it, and it appears the follow error:

```
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider
nov 06, 2013 9:08:53 AM org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter warn
ADVERTENCIA: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
nov 06, 2013 9:08:53 AM org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter error
GRAVE: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
nov 06, 2013 9:08:53 AM org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter warn
ADVERTENCIA: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
```

This is my "applicationContext.xml" where I connect with database and I map the resources.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <!-- Configuración del datasource para hibernate -->

    <bean
        id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/secretaria</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>secretaria</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>1234</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Factoria de sesiones de Hibernate -->
    <bean
        id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref local="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources"> 
            <list>
                <value>secretaria/beans/prueba.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>secretaria/beans/lotes.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>secretaria/beans/expediente.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>secretaria/beans/prorroga.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>secretaria/beans/plurianual.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>secretaria/beans/modificado.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>secretaria/beans/empresa.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">
                    update
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                    true
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">
                    true
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Interceptor para transacciones de Hibernate -->    
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <import resource="classpath:actions.spring.xml"/>   
    <import resource="classpath:dao.spring.xml"/>   
    <import resource="classpath:services.spring.xml"/>
</beans>
```

I've tried to update the springframeworks libraries, the tomcat, reset the server and cry, but anything works. What can I do??? Thanks for your answer!!!

Comment: Sounds like your application is trying to access a database on another server and being refused. I'd check your firewall configuration.

Comment: Hi!!!  This is my configuration in my "applicationContext.xml"                <bean
  id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName">
   <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
  </property>
  <property name="url">
   <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/secretaria</value>
  </property>
  <property name="username">
   <value>secretaria</value>
  </property>
  <property name="password">
   <value>1234</value>
  </property>
 </bean>

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Spring and MyBatis, and I have the same error as you.
I think that you should configure the dbcp connection pool with two more properties, like this(in your application-context.xml):

```
    <bean id="vrsRankDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${vrs_rank.jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${vrs_rank.jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${vrs_rank.jdbc.pwd}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="3"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from dual"/>
</bean>
```

The property "initialSize" is the initial number of connections when the pool is created, which is default to 0; "testOnBorrow" property defaults to true, but it takes effect when you configured the property"validationQuery", the value of which MUST be a SELECT statement that returns at least one row.

For more information, please reference "http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html" and "http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-spring-config-connpooling.html".

I hope that you all could solve similiar problems.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> <property name="url">
>       <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/secretaria?autoReconnect=true</value>
>   </property>

I'm not sure about Spring support but you could try to add the following property too:

> <property name="validationQuery">
>     <value>Select 1</value>
>   </property>